# Program is unable to find .so files when running through gdb

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries

Im trying to debug my c++ program.  I can run it fine normally but when I attempt to run the exe through gdb it suddenly cant find my so files.  The directory is in my path and when I try "show environment" in gdb the path still shows the directory but it cant find the so files.

I ran

```
gdb --args ${EXE} ${ARGS}
```

and I get back

`error while loading shared libraries: libX.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.`

Comment: Please add more information to your question, eg. how do you start gdb (arguments...), which command do you enter in gdb, which messages gdb shows as response...

Comment: @RYoda Ive added the how I call and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the shared library search path using the command: 
`(gdb) set solib-search-path`.
To check which libraries are already loaded:
`(gdb) info sharedlibrary`.
To manually load a shared library if it is not loaded: `(gdb) sharedlibrary libTest`.
The following command may also be useful to check which files have their symbols loaded already: `(gdb) info sources`.

Comment: `solib-search-path` affects where GDB itself looks for shared libraries. It has _no_ effect on the program being debugged, which is the problem here.